# Uncaught TypeError when calling drawImage function

Tags: javascript, canvas, reactjs

Bonjour!

I'm trying to make use of canvas element under ReactJS. I'm getting an error when i call drawImage(). Everything work except the drawImage()..  ?

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'

```
var Canvas = React.createClass({
    componentDidUpdate: function() {
        console.log("componentDidUpdate");
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        var context = this.getDOMNode().getContext('2d');
        this.paint(context);
    },

    paint: function(context) {
        context.save();
        context.fillStyle = '#F00';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        context.drawImage("image.jpg", 0, 0);
        context.restore();
    },

    render: function(){
        return <canvas width={400} height={400} />;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you sure the image.jpg has been loaded before you call drawImage()?

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp):

> Note: You cannot call the drawImage() method before the image has loaded. To ensure that the image has been loaded, you can call drawImage() from window.onload() or from document.getElementById("imageID").onload.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable solution. Don't let the imminent W3S haters get you down. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me.

I did `drawImage(x, y, img);` by accident, when it should be `drawImage(img, x, y);` Check to **make sure your arguments are in the correct order**

After I did that, it still didn't work. I was using `Promises.all()` (from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53290838/2336212) and didn't realize that the `result` was an array of all passed in values. I mistakenly passed `resolve(images)`. Instead of receiving an array of images, I received an array of arrays of images. Make sure you **only pass a single object back through `resolve()`** unless you expect a 2D array. I changed it to `resolve(image)` and it worked.