# why image is not converted into base64?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert my attached image into `base64` .I tried like this, but getting error .

https://jsbin.com/lubosabore/edit?html,js,console,output

```
    function getBase64Image(img) {
            // Create an empty canvas element
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;

            // Copy the image contents to the canvas
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            // Get the data-URL formatted image
            // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
            // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
            // will re-encode the image.
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

            return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        }


$(function(){
 // alert()
  $('#fileId').on('change', function (e) {
            console.log('ddd');
            var file = e.target.files[0];
            console.log(getBase64Image(file))
        })
})
```

i attached one `png` value

it is not printing the base64 value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError when calling drawImage function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457605/uncaught-typeerror-when-calling-drawimage-function)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu too complicated - there's no need for a server round trip  for this.

Comment: @user944513 thanks for including a jsbin link, that helps, and in the future it also helps to include the exact error message with your questions.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

So a [`File` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications) like `e.target.files[0]` won't work.  We need to convert it into an `HTMLImageElement` first.  Here is how to do that (from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906734/how-to-upload-image-into-html5-canvas)):

```
function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
}
```

Now you have a `HTMLImageElement`.  However, you really don't need it, or the `canvas` at all:  `event.target.result` from the `FileReader` is already a `data:` URL like you want.

Comment: please jsbin link